# Django: ManyToManyField appears as empty on my template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm having an issue displaying a ManyToManyField in a character profile template using Django.

The template has to show an avatar, alongside some information about the character, including a list of guilds this character had joined. But, when I try to display that list, it appears as if it is empty. I had a look into my site administration page, and that information is there, so I have confirmation that the data can be displayed in my template. I just don't know how. How could I handle that?

These are my models:

```
""" Modelos de la aplicación de personajes """
from django.db import models

class Guild(models.Model):
    """ Modelo del clan """
    guild_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    rank = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.guild_name

class Character(models.Model):
    """ Modelo del personaje """
    character_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    race = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True)
    character_guilds = models.ManyToManyField(Guild, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.character_name+': '+self.race+' '+self.job+' level '+str(self.level)+'. '
```

My view.py file:

```
def characterprofile(request, pk):
    """ Método para mostrar el perfil de un personaje """
    template = '../templates/character/characterProfile.html'
    profile = Character.objects.get(pk=pk)
    guilds = profile.character_guilds.all()
    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'guilds': guilds
    }
    return render (request, template, context)
```

And my template.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <header>
        <h2>{{ profile.character_name }}'s profile</h2>
    </header>
    <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'characters' %}">Return</a>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            {% if profile.avatar %}
            <img class="rounded" src="{{ profile.avatar.url }}" width="184" height="184">
            {% else %}
            <p>There is no avatar to display here.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <br>
        <h4>Information</h4>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush-sm">
            <li class="list-group-item">Name: {{ profile.character_name }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Level: {{ profile.level }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Race: {{ profile.race }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Gender: {{ profile.gender }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Job: {{ profile.job }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                Guilds: 
                {% for g in guilds %} 
                    {{ g }} 
                {%endfor%}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <footer>
        <span>Copyright© 2020</span>
    </footer>
{% endblock %}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried leaving the guilds part in the view and just use {% for g in profile.character_guilds.all %}{{ g }} {% endfor %} ?

Comment: @errorinpersona yep, same story: data is not displayed in the template.

Comment: Did you solve your problem or do you need further help?

Comment: @errorinpersona my problem has already been solved. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work. There was another view causing conflicts. `form.save(commit=False)` can cause some trouble with MtM relationships, so I changed it to True.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `primary key`, because with database when a row is deleted and you recreate a new one the primary key does not restart from 1.

For instance try somthing like this in your view function:

```
profile = Character.objects.get(character_name=character_name)
```

hope it help

Comment: Tried it, and added this line of code to the template: ```{{ profile.character_guilds.all }}```. The result is an empty querySet. What does that mean? The guilds still are showing up in the admin site.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, sorry !! in your view function, below `profile = Character.objects.get(pk=pk)` try for exemple: `print(profile.character_name)` and see what it show in the command line

Comment: I did, and I get the following: character.Guild.None